# Denstructor deletes a member which is already replaced?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am pretty new to the C++ world... 
I have a question about destructors in C++.

If there is a class like:

```
class TestClass {
public:
   double *array;    
}
```

When I put a pointer of one array to `*array` and put again another and delete Testclass instance, then I can no longer access the older one?

It becomes an error:

```
int main() {
    TestClass tc;
    tc.array = new double[10];
    double *array2 = tc.array;
    tc.array[3]=9;
    tc.array = new double[10];
    delete &tc; // <------------------- this one.
    std::cout<<array2[3]<<std::endl;
//    std::cout<<tc.array[3]<<array2[3]<<std::endl;
}
```

If there is no `delete &tc` and activate the commentline (the last line),
 '09' shows up, (tc.array[3] != array2[3] => tc.array != array2)
 which does not mean tc.arrray is not the one in *array2 ??

What is wrong?

Comment: You should **never** be deleting an object that was allocated on the stack, in your case, `tc`. What are you doing?

Comment: Only `delete` something that has been created with operator `new`.   `tc` was not created using operator `new`, so should not be deleted.

Comment: Thank you. This test was related to my question about what if two classes share an array and the one of them is deconstructed..

Comment: `deconstructor` -- Just to let you know, the correct term is *destructor*, not *deconstructor*.

Comment: `tc.array = new double[10];` -- The first call to `new[]` was never deallocated, thus the second time you did this results in a memory leak unless you delete `array2`

Comment: @Frontear -- no, this doesn't depend on what the destructor does. `delete`ing something that wasn't created with `new` results in undefined behavior. Don't try to reason about what might happen. Just don't do it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It is not a memory leak since there is an accessible reference to it via `array2`.

Comment: Well I updated my comment a while ago to state that array2 needs to be deleted.  But if you look at the code, the memory leak is there since the OP did not `delete [] array2;`.

Answer (score 2):

The `tc` is a function-scoped variable (allocated on the stack). It's not allocated with `new`. You can't delete it. it will be freed automatically when the function return

Comment: `malloc` doesn't allocate objects, it allocates storage (in which objects can later be constructed)

Comment: Additionally, anything allocated via `malloc` cannot be `deleted`. This is undefined behaviour, and instead you should be using `free`. Furthermore, `malloc` won't call the constructor, and `free` won't call the destructor. This kind of response can lead to confusion for new programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with raw pointers is somewhat tricky and your class would probably benefit from using a `std::vector<double>` instead of a raw pointer. Another choice could be a `std::unique_ptr<double[]>` that handles deleting the pointer for you.

That said, if you want to try it out, you should know when and what to delete.

`tc` is an automatic variable. You didn't create `tc` using `new` so you should not `delete` it. It will be destroyed when it goes out of scope - when the program leaves the block in which `tc` was created.

You haven't defined a destructor for `TestClass` so the memory to which `array` points will still be allocated even after `tc` is destroyed. The destructor would typically look like this:

```
~TestClass() {
    delete[] array;
}
```

You also assign directly to `tc`s internal pointer, which is dangerous. You should have just as many `delete[]` as you have `new[]`s, which is not the case in your program, so it'll leak. You should typically hide the internal pointer so it can't be reassigned without the object owning it having control.

For manual memory management to work properly, there are some member functions you should consider:

- Copy constructor
- Move constructor
- Copy assignment operator
- Move assignment operator
- Destructor

You can read more about those here: [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

---

Here's an example of what your class could look like with the 5 member functions mentioned above plus a default constructor, a converting constructor taking a pointer as parameter and two subscript operators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility> // std::move, std::swap, std::exchange

class TestClass {
public:
    // default constructor
    TestClass() :
        array(nullptr) // member initializer
    {
        std::cout << "default ctor\n";
    }

    // converting constructor - refuse lvalue pointers since we want to make sure
    //                          that we "own" the pointer
    TestClass(double*&& p) : array(p) {
        std::cout << "converting ctor " << p << "\n";
    }

    // copy constructing without knowledge about the size of the array isn't possible
    TestClass(const TestClass&) = delete;

    // move construction works though
    TestClass(TestClass&& rhs) :
        array(std::exchange(rhs.array, nullptr)) // steal pointer from rhs
    {
        std::cout << "move ctor\n";
    }

    // copy assignment without knowledge about the size of the array isn't possible
    TestClass& operator=(const TestClass&) = delete;

    // move assignment works though
    TestClass& operator=(TestClass&& rhs) {
        std::cout << "move assignment\n";
        // swap pointers with rhs - let rhs delete[] our current pointer
        std::swap(array, rhs.array);
        return *this;
    }

    ~TestClass() { // destructor
        delete[] array;
    }

    // subscripting support
    double& operator[](size_t idx) { return array[idx]; }
    double operator[](size_t idx) const { return array[idx]; }

private: // hide your raw pointer from direct access
    double* array;
};

void printer(const TestClass& tc, size_t idx) {
    // use const version of operator[] in the class
    std::cout << tc[idx] << "\n";
}

int main() {
    TestClass tc; // default ctor

    // use the converting constructor that creates a TestClass object from a pointer.
    // It is then move assigned to tc
    tc = new double[10];
    tc[3] = 1;         // use the non-const version of operator[] in the class
    printer(tc, 3);

    double* a = new double[10];
    // tc = a; // this won't work since we don't accept lvalues in assignment
    tc = std::move(a); // make an xvalue to allow the assignment. "a" should not be
                       // delete[]-ed after this since we granted tc the possibillity
                       // to take ownership the pointer.
    tc[3] = 2;
    printer(tc, 3);
}
```